# Updating and reverting changes with JPA persistence

Tags: java, database, jpa, updates, reverting

I have questing regarding JPA persistence. I want to change values of specific column (for e.g. 1 to 2), and fetch corresponding rows further (which are having column value 2). If other service gives some error, I want to revert column values to 1.

Can we do this in JPA?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Transactional annotation to your method. so, you can change value from 1 to 2. Then fetch corresponding rows. Anywhere exception happens, it will be reverted back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring data JPA, try something like that:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE ...")
```